How to Merge Multiple Rows with Same Unique ID into One in Python with Pandas
I have seen some questions similar to this, but none I could find tackle how to unstack multiple columns. I have successfully unstacked a single column using.
df = df.groupby(['id', 'entity'])['true_value'].aggregate('first').unstack(sort=True)

However, I would like to turn this
id entity     true_value         extracted_value    rater  ratio
1  student    no                 yes                FALSE  100
1  address    303 lake way       303 lake way       TRUE   100
1  email      kyle@gmail.com     kyle123@gmail.com  FALSE  0
2  student    yes                yes                TRUE   100
2  address    15 putin ave       15 putnam ave      FALSE  0
2  email      matt@gmail.com     matt@gmail.com     TRUE   95

Into this
id student_true   student_extracted  student_rater  student_ratio  address_true       address_extracted  address_rater  address_ratio  email_true         email_extracted     email_rater     email_ratio
1  no             yes                FALSE          100            303 lake way       303 lake way       TRUE           100            kyle@gmail.com     kyle123@gmail.com   FALSE           0
2  yes            yes                TRUE           100            15 e putnam ave    15 putnam ave      FALSE          0              matt@gmail.com     matt@gmail.com      TRUE            95

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
I have tried using groupby and unstack in many different ways to get the desired result, but have been unable.

pivot and then rename the columns:
out = df.pivot(index="id", columns="entity").reset_index()
out.columns = [f"{col[1]}_{col[0]}".replace("_value", "") for col in out.columns]

   _id  address_true      email_true student_true address_extracted  ... email_rater student_rater  address_ratio  email_ratio  student_ratio
0    1  303 lake way  kyle@gmail.com           no      303 lake way  ...       False         False            100            0            100
1    2  15 putin ave  matt@gmail.com          yes     15 putnam ave  ...        True          True              0           95            100

[2 rows x 13 columns]


Thank you for the quick response. I get this error when I run the code on entire dataset- "raise ValueError("Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape") ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape". This is why I originally was trying to use groupby.
Is there another method that would work if my index contains duplicates? Thanks again for your help.

@Nick Add a reset_index before pivot.
